# Mover archivos de una carpeta a otra en Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una base de datos de números telefónicos y tengo una carpeta con algunos archivos de excel nombrados con algunos números telefónicos. Quiero mover esos archivos a otra carpeta.

Actualmente en un rango de celda del documento en `excel` tengo los numeros telefónicos y este código es el que utilizo en el `visual basic`, pero me marca **error**.

¿Qué podría ser el error?

¿Cómo escribo las rutas y/o código?

```
Sub MoverArchivos()
    
    Dim carpetaOrigen As String
    Dim carpetaDestino As String
    Dim telefonos As Variant
    Dim telefono As Variant
    Dim nombreArchivo As String
    Dim rutaArchivo As String
    Dim rutaDestino As String
    
    ' Carpeta donde se encuentran los archivos originales
    carpetaOrigen = "C:\ArchivosOrigen\"
    
    ' Carpeta donde se moverán los archivos que coincidan con los números telefónicos
    carpetaDestino = "C:\ArchivosDestino\"
    
    ' Rango de celdas donde se encuentran los números telefónicos
    telefonos = Range("A1:A10").Value ' Modifica el rango según tu caso
    
    ' Recorrer la carpeta de archivos
    rutaArchivo = carpetaOrigen & "*.*"
    nombreArchivo = Dir(rutaArchivo)
    
    Do While nombreArchivo <> ""
        
        ' Obtener el nombre de archivo sin la extensión
        nombreArchivo = Left(nombreArchivo, InStrRev(nombreArchivo, ".") - 1)
        
        ' Buscar coincidencias con los números telefónicos
        For Each telefono In telefonos
            If nombreArchivo = telefono Then
                
                ' Mover el archivo a la nueva carpeta
                rutaDestino = carpetaDestino & nombreArchivo & ".xlsx"
                FileCopy carpetaOrigen & nombreArchivo & ".xlsx", rutaDestino
                Kill carpetaOrigen & nombreArchivo & ".xlsx"
                
                Exit For
            End If
        Next telefono
        
        ' Obtener el siguiente archivo de la carpeta de origen
        nombreArchivo = Dir
        
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Proceso finalizado."
    
End Sub
```

Comment: En qué parte del código te marca el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegurate que el formato de la ruta lo estes escribiendo bien, yo intente hacer pruebas y me fallaba hasta que me di cuenta que faltaba el ultimo signo " \ ", basate como escribi la ruta a tus necesidades, espero te ayude

```
carpetaOrigen = "C:\User\Desktop\Carpeta1\"
carpetaDestino = "C:\User\Desktop\Carpeta2\"
```

Comment: Gracias si era eso que me estaba faltando en mi codigo original